# D3: change font size of axis labels

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want to specify a font size for the labels of a time axis created with D3. I've tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19681335/5522601) with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/speedymcs/o160fb10/), but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried

```
d3.selectAll(".xAxis>.tick>text")
  .each(function(d, i){
    d3.select(this).style("font-size",30);
  });
```

to no avail. It can't be that hard...

Comment: The fiddle you've linked to works fine. Try changing the font size.

Comment: Huh, now that you said that I tried it in different browsers. It does work for me in Chrome but not in Edge or Firefox, where the font size remains completely unchanged at about 15px. Any idea why?

Comment: Okay, one has to specify the unit, i.e. `"60px"` instead of just `60`. Gee

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out that a unitless number is [technically not a valid CSS font size specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7907764/5522601) and that it may depend on the browser whether it is ignored or not. Therefore, use

```
d3.select(this).style("font-size","30px");
```

instead of

```
d3.select(this).style("font-size",30);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using below Code can set any styles of X label

```
const formatXLabel=()=>{
   const parent = document.querySelector("."+ props.xAxis.class);
   for(let x = 0; x<parent.children.length; x++) {

       const ticks = parent.children.item(x);
       if(ticks !==null && ticks.className.baseVal === 'tick') {
           try {
               const text = ticks.querySelector("text");
               for (let sp in props.xAxis.labelStyles) {
                   text.style[sp.toString()] = props.xAxis.labelStyles[sp];
               }
           }catch (e){
            console.log(e);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't think this has anything to do with D3 though...

Comment: After Rendering chart using D3, I used this code to format x axis label.