# Placing D3 tooltip in cursor location

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) in my visualisation. I now want to add tooltips to elements that are very wide and may extend out of the visible canvas. By default, the tooltip is shown in the horizontal center of an object, which means in my case that the tooltip might not be in the visible area. What I need is the tooltip showing up in the horizontal position of the cursor but I don't know how to change the tooltip position correctly. I can set an offset and I can get the coordinates of the cursor, but what I can't get is the initial position of the tooltip so that I can compute the right offset. Nor can I set an absolute position:

```
            .on("mouseover",function(d){
                var coordinates = [0, 0];
                coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
                var x = coordinates[0];
                var y = coordinates[1];
                tip.offset([-20,20]); // this works
                tip.attr("x",40); // this doesn't
                tip.show(d);
            })
```

Comment: You're right, I don't know where is my mind...  just deleted the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previously stated answer did not work for me (*and cannot be modified as "suggested edit queue is full.."*), but with some minor adjustments, it is working fine:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    var x = d3.event.x,
        y = d3.event.y;

    tip.show(d);

    tip.style('top', y-10 + 'px'); // edited
    tip.style('left', x+'px'); // edited
  })
```

Comment: I don't use D3 anymore, but I'll take your word and accept this answer. Are you using Edge or Firefox by any change? The problem then seems to be that without `px`, some browsers do not accept the coordinates as valid CSS. (Ironically, I found that out myself [five years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34891327/5522601))

Comment: That is a good note - I was using Firefox. I just tested both code snippets in Firefox and Chrome & Edge (chromium based). Using the suggested `+'px' ` makes the tooltip compatible in all three, otherwise only chromium based browsers can deal with the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use offset, you can get the initial position of the tooltip after tip.show(d):

```
tip.style('top');
tip.style('left');
```

Similarly, to set the absolute position:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
        var x = d3.event.x,
            y = d3.event.y;

        tip.show(d);

        tip.style('top', y);
        tip.style('left', x);
      })
```

Comment: I can get the coordinates but I can't set them, e.g. `tip.style("top", 20)` has no effect and I've placed it both before and after `tip.show(d)`...

Comment: the coordinates do work when used with 'px' - see below.